# Why the presheaf image of an injective morphism of sheaves is automatically a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Why the presheaf image of an injective morphism of sheaves is automatically a sheaf? This question appears also here [Presheaf image of a monomorphism of sheaves is a sheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119306/presheaf-image-of-a-monomorphism-of-sheaves-is-a-sheaf). But the answear is actually a counter example for other question.

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Actually that answer is for other question. It is a counterexample. So my question is not duplicate!!

Comment: @PregatireMatematica But did you see Hoot's comment? If $\phi : \mathcal F \to \mathcal G$ is an injective morphism of sheaves, then ${\rm Im}(\phi)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal F$, and therefore, it is certainly a sheaf.